# usage of single trailing(@) in SAS for delimited data

Tags: sas

Can you please tell me if we can use single trailing (@) for delimited data
rather than fixed width.

Thanks,
Nikhila

Comment: Yes.  But this doesn't really look like a SO question.  Can you provide an example where you would need to use it?

Comment: I was just working on some examples. I have a file like below                          nikhila,26,hyd,btech
akhila,24,blr,btech
nitesh,20,blr,bmm                                                                                                         i want the data based on last 2 columns

Comment: Can you put the data in the question?  What do you want the output to look like. Looks like you just want to ignore the first two columns.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it looks like the question is really how to skip columns in delimited data.  A simple way is to read the value into a variable that you later drop. Or even read it into a variable that you want and then overwrite it with the value from the column you do want to keep.

```
data want ;
  infile cards dsd truncover ;
  length var1 var2 $20;
  input 3*var1 var2 ;
cards;
nikhila,26,hyd,btech
akhila,24,blr,btech
nitesh,20,blr,bmm
;
```

Comment: interesting - what does the `3*` do?

Comment: Just what it looks like. It will make it do three times. So `3*var1` is the same as `var1 var1 var1`.

Comment: I see...  so it overwrites and you end up with the third value in the variable.  Nice!